# sql database index doesn't work

Tags: sql, indexing

I am using Sql database and I have indexed some tables. In some tables the index worked, but there is an integer column in one of the tables that I use usaully with the order by clause, I have indexed it but I can see in the execution plan window that it doesn't get used by Sql , no matter what i try.
does anyone have any idea please?

Comment: Can you show the query, the tables, the explain plan, tell us how many rows the table contain and what dbms you are using?

Comment: Most likely an other index is already being used.

Comment: If your index is not covering (includes all columns in the query), the DBMS probably decides to table scan instead, and rightfully so

Comment: I have half a million records in the table. I am using sql server db. I cannot cover all the columns because one of them is text type. I think that might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because it is not being used doesn't mean it isn't working. SQL Server will analyse your query and decide if using the index is a good idea or not.

Maybe if you post the table and the index we can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

One explanation is that you don't have a `not null` constraint on your column.

Indexes does not contain null keys, so your index may not contain all rows of the table. So, the engine cannot use it, because it is not sure that all values will be in it, and will make a table scan.